# WP - Advanced Custom Fields get values from field to radio buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm working with this code

```
<div class="text2">
<h1>test</h1>
<?php 

$colors = get_field('color');

if( $colors ): ?>
<p>Color: <?php echo implode(', ', $colors); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php

$field_name = "color";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);

if( $field )
{
  echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
    {
      echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
    }
  echo '</select>';
}

?>
```

And I'm getting output like that:

[image: Output]

As you can see, the first part of code with implode working great - I choose brass and gold colors for this article. But the choices field generating every value from field. My target is to get all options from choices field but only these, which i marked.

The right output in that case will be only 2 options - brass and gold from choices field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if( $field )
{
  echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
    {
      echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
    }
  echo '</select>';
}
```

.. with this:

```
if( $field )
{
  echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
    $selected = $field['value'];
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
    {
      if ( in_array( $k, $selected ) ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
      }
    }
  echo '</select>';
}
```

.. or a shorter version:

```
if( $field )
{
  echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
    foreach( $field['value'] as $value )
    {
      $label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
      echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $label . '</option>';
    }
  echo '</select>';
}
```

[EDIT]To make a group of `radio` buttons:

(You can change the CSS `class`es — `radiobox-group` and/or `radiobox`. The `radio` buttons also use `color` as their `name`.)

```
if( $field )
{
  echo '<div class="radiobox-group">';
    foreach( $field['value'] as $value )
    {
      $label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
      $checked = '';

      echo '<label class="radiobox">';
        printf( '<input type="radio" name="color" value="%s"%s /> ',
          esc_attr( $value ), $checked );
        echo esc_html( $label );
      echo '</label>';
    }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I dont know if this is the right way. I need dynamically get colors from aray witch im choosing by custom fields for every article separately. U think your code will work that way?

Comment: Why not you try it out? The `$my_colors` variable holds only the colors that you want to appear in the `select`/drop-down menu. But yes, you'd need to edit the value of that variable, if for example, you also want "silver", "pink", "white", etc. colors to be in the drop-down menu there.

Comment: No. Thank you for your help but what I need is getting that values dynamically to the choices field. Like that i think but my code does not work.`if( $field )
{
  echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
    {
      if($v == in_array($colors)){
        echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
      }
    }
  echo '</select>';
}

?>`

Comment: Please try the updated code snippet. That one should work well.

Comment: One more thing :| Is there some way how I can make that menu list to radio buttons? :) Ty again.

Comment: It's my pleasure! =)